# How can i update another tables after adding record to a table in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two same tables created in SQL Server 2008.

What I need is:

**Add the newest data inserted in `table1` into `table2`.**

Is that possible?

Something like services or triggers or stored procedures?

I think that I have to use triggers, but I don't know how.

I have these two tables:

```
table1  ( field1,field2,field3 )
table2  ( field1,field2,field3 )
```

when i insert into table1 i need table2 to be updated as the procedure below:

```
> IF NotExist(field1=value) in table2 THEN INSERT Into table2 ELSE UPDATE table2
> with new field1 value.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```sql
USE DatabaseName;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('Sch.UpdateSecondTable', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER Sch.UpdateSecondTable;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Sch.UpdateSecondTable
ON FirstTable
AFTER INSERT
AS 
    INSERT INTO SecondTable 
    SELECT * FROM Inserted
GO
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b65c6/1)

However, if you want to update the second table form with the inserted values from the first table, try this instead of the `INSERT` clause:

```sql
UPDATE t2
SET t2.name = t1.name
FROM SecondTable t2
INNER JOIN inserted t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6ee5/1)

**Update:** If you want to insert only the values that doesn't exist in the second tabl3e. If these tables are of the same structures, i.e the same column numbers and the same data type. You can use the `EXCEPT` set operator to do this like so:

```sql
   UPDATE t2
   SET t2.name = t1.name
   FROM SecondTable t2
   INNER JOIN
   (
     SELECT * FROM inserted t1
     EXCEPT SELECT * FROM SECONDTABLE
   ) t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14b44/1)

If not use the standard way to do this like so:

```sql
   UPDATE t2
   SET t2.name = t1.name
   FROM SecondTable t2
   INNER JOIN
   (
     SELECT * FROM inserted t1
     WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM SECONDTABLE)
   ) t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e70ba/1)

Comment: thanks
i have to check the second table for the existance of the record to check whether it should insert a new record in table2 or update the record in table2
how can i check it in trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use trigger, its not a big deal, do some research, you will get on the internet.

Comment: i hope that you give me an example

Comment: Well first you need to study & try to code yourself, then if you have any problem in coding you will get help here. But you can't expect the full code sample in stackoverflow.com, its against the policy.

Comment: It's Really simple you just need to search "After insert trigger: and you will find examples on Stackoverflow or other sites.